# Intellisense Issues in strings and methods/members

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

While coding in C# for Visual Studio 2010, I've noticed, that for some reason, after creating a delegate method, or using the "Extract method" menu option from Visual Studio, my IntelliSense decides it wants to go overboard. It starts activating inside a string, trying to complete stuff from outside (for instance, if I type "To be continued..." as I start to type continued, it suggests "const" as an option, thinking I'm still coding, and not recognizing I'm in a string.

Also, when it starts doing the above, it also starts doing stuff like suggesting a while loop, while trying to do a Debug.WriteLine, and the Debug class has no members listed in the IntelliSense popup window, all it lists is base classes for my current namespaces.

Now if I push <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> manually, I get the proper intellisense options.

Sometimes, closing all open files, and reopening them fixes it; sometimes I have to completely close visual studio and reopen it to fix it.

Is anyone else experiencing similar issues, or know of any fixes to the issue?

Comment: Do you have any extensions or addons installed? Try disabling all of them and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Only DevExpress, vanilla install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funnily enough, since extensions were suggested as being the cause of the issue, an extension is actually what fixed the issue for me.

It seems ReSharper overwrites default Intellisense handling, and the folks over at ReSharper seem to do it better than DevExpress, or Visual Studio, as even just installing Resharper, and uninstalling it seemed to fix it.

I've left ReSharper permanently installed on one dev environment, and have been using it consistently now for over a year, and haven't ran into this issue once, and I used to run into it weekly, or bi-weekly.